# show hide Menu(REACT)(TAILWINDCSS)

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'

import LOGO from '../././';

import HeaderImagen '../././';


export const main = () => {

  const [Toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
          <header className='bg-blue-500 sm:flex sm:justify-center'>
                <div className='flex items-center px-4 py-3 justify-between sm:pt-2'>
                    <div className=''>
                        <img className='h-6' src={LOGO} alt='LOGO'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className=' text-green-400 sm:hidden cursor-pointer' onClick={()=> setToggle(!Toggle)}>
                        <GoThreeBars size='2rem'/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {Toggle ? <div className='px-2 pt-2 font-bold  sm:flex'>
                    <a href='https://www.google.com' className=' flex justify-center px-3 py-1 text-white hover:text-green-500 '>SkillSet</a>
                    <a href='https://www.google.com' className=' flex justify-center px-3 py-1 text-white hover:text-green-500 '>Curriculum</a>
                    <a href='https://www.google.com' className=' flex justify-center px-3 py-1 text-white hover:text-green-500 '>Contact Me</a>
                </div> : '' }
            </header>
        </>

    )
}
```

tengo un problema con la parte del show/hide. de un elemento. cuando cierro el menu y estiro el navegador para mostrar otras resoluciones entonces el menu no aparece. pero si vuelvo a la resoluciones movil y dejo el menu abierto entonces al estirar el navegador el menu sale. **si no me di a entender bien pueden revisar el video que deje abajo para comprender mejor el problema**

https://i.imgur.com/CyMzFxd.mp4